# Scraped texts saved in a variable returns only the last text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, environment-variables

I'm using selenium to scrape all the articles about a given keyword from the first page of a news website. The code is as below:

```
homepage = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Awww.ilgiornale.it+immigrati&t=h_&ia=web"
driver.get(homepage)
links_giornale = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='result__a js-result-title-link']")
hrefs_giornale = []
for link in links_giornale[1:]:
    pages = link.get_attribute("href")
    hrefs_giornale.append(pages)

#to accept cookies the first time I access the website
driver.get(hrefs_giornale[0])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@mode='primary']").click()

for href in hrefs_giornale:
    driver.get(href)
    element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='content__body typography']")
    for art in element:
        print(art.text)
```

In the last line, if I print art.text it correctly prints all the articles scraped from the first webpage, but if I save the text in a variable or append all the text to a list, it returns only the last article. I've tried to use art.text in a variable, to use a list comprehension and to use append() but the result is always the same. Could you help me understand what the problem is? Because I need to manipulate all this text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
all_texts = []

for href in hrefs_giornale:
    driver.get(href)
    element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='content__body typography']")
    for art in element:
        all_texts.append(art.text)

for t in all_texts:
    print(t)
```

---

https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-add-a-string-to-a-list-as-an-element-in-python